# wso2 esb iterate mediator thread safe?

Tags: wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

I have below iterate Seq,

```
  <iterate attachPath="//Test"
    expression="///Test" preservePayload="true">
    <target>
      <sequence>
       <header name="Action" scope="default" value="action1"/>
       <send>endpoint 1</send>
      </sequence>
    </target>
    <target>
      <sequence>
       <header name="Action" scope="default" value="action2"/>
       <send>endpoint 2</send>
      </sequence>
    </target>
  </iterate>
```

so does the "Action" is thread safe in each iterate target\seq.

if so, in"aggregate", can i access the property/header inside the target\seq?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "SOAP-Action is  thread safe" ?

Comment: iterate is parallel, in target\seq have same header name "Action", so if in the first target\seq set to "Action" to "action1", second  target\seq is using this value.

Comment: Actually, I did't get what you said. 'SOAP Action' is a SOAP Header to specify the required action to be executed out of the list of available actions with a WSDL end-point right? Can you please elaborate from there?

Comment: Yes, this action is for WSDL end-point operations. Different call/operations should have different action.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether its thread safe. But to workaround your doubt, I think the following information would help.

There is a property called "Sequential Mediation" in the iterate mediator. If it is set to true, it will process the iterated messaged sequentially. See the following documentation.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Iterate+Mediator